# django admin form empty after POST

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am having trouble posting data in an admin form. Some fields get empty after clicking the save button, others not (the inlines are keeping their data). See the images for a better explanation of the problem.

Entering some data:
[image: Before post]
After clicking on [save]...
[image: After clicking on save]
Validation error! (The model is not saved)

My ModelForm is quite simple: I am just changing the form field for one of the m2m model fields.

```
class News(models.Model):
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department, blank=True, related_name='news', through='NewsDepartmentMembership')
    research_groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True, related_name='news', through='NewsGroupMembership')
    related_news = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    people_involved = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True, related_name='news')

    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), unique_for_date='pub_date',
                        help_text=_('A slug is a short name which uniquely identifies the news item for this day'), )
    excerpt = RichTextField(_('Excerpt'), blank=True)
    content = RichTextField(_('Content'), blank=True)

    is_published = models.BooleanField(_('Published'), default=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Publication date'), default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_feat = models.BooleanField(
        _('Featured'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Administrators may use this checkbox to promote news to the main news page')
    )

    published = PublishedNewsManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
    featured = FeaturedNewsManager()

class NewNewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News

    related_news = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=News.objects.none(),
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name=_('articles'),
            is_stacked=False,
        )
    )

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewNewsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(user, 'is_superuser'):
            self.fields['related_news'].queryset = get_objects_for_user(user, ('news.change_news',)).filter(
                is_published__exact=True).order_by('pub_date')
        else:
            self.fields['related_news'].queryset = News.published.order_by('pub_date')
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['related_news'].initial = self.instance.related_news.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        news = super(NewNewsForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            news.save()

        if news.pk:
            news.related_news = self.cleaned_data['related_news']
            self.save_m2m()

        return news
```

The ModelAdmin is quite complicated, it inherits 2 ModelAdmins. [The 1st one](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/blob/master/modeltranslation/admin.py) comes from the django-modeltranslation package. I adapted the 2nd one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746735), just to perform cross inline formsets validation. It's working in other packages without any problem (at least until today). I just have to override the method is_cross_valid to define the cross inline validation

```
class NewsAdmin(TranslationAdmin, ModelAdminWithInlines):
    fields = ('title', 'slug_en', 'slug_nb', 'excerpt', 'content', 'is_published', 'pub_date', 'related_news', 'is_feat')
    inlines = (DepartmentsNewsInline, GroupsNewsInline, PersonNewsInline)
    form = NewNewsForm
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug_en': ('title',), 'slug_nb': ('title',)}

    class Media:
        js = (
            'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
            'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js',
            'modeltranslation/js/tabbed_translation_fields.js',
        )
        css = {
            'screen': ('modeltranslation/css/tabbed_translation_fields.css',),
        }

    def queryset(self, request):
        return get_objects_for_user(request.user, (u'news.change_news', ))

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'related_news':
            return get_objects_for_user(request.user, ('news.change_news',), ).order_by('pub_date')
        return super(NewsAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def is_cross_valid(self, request, form, formsets):
        valid = True
        # my validation code goes here...
        return valid


    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if not request.user.groups.filter(name__exact='administration') and not request.user.is_superuser:
            return ('is_feat', )
        return ()

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if super(NewsAdmin, self).has_change_permission(request, obj):
            return True
        return request.user.has_perm('news.change_news', obj)
```

This is my ModelAdminWithInlines, almost the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746735):

```
class ModelAdminWithInlines(ModelAdmin):
    """
    Cross formsets validation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746735
    """
    def is_cross_valid(self, request, form, formsets):
        """
        To perform cross-formset validation.
        Should be overriden in every inheriting class.
        """
        return True

    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        """The 'add' admin view for this model."""
        model = self.model
        opts = model._meta

        if not self.has_add_permission(request):
            raise PermissionDenied

        ModelForm = self.get_form(request)
        formsets = []
        inline_instances = self.get_inline_instances(request, None)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_object = self.save_form(request, form, change=False)
                form_validated = True
            else:
                form_validated = False
                new_object = self.model()
            prefixes = {}
            for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets(request), inline_instances):
                prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix()
                prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
                if prefixes[prefix] != 1 or not prefix:
                    prefix = "%s-%s" % (prefix, prefixes[prefix])
                formset = FormSet(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES,
                                  instance=new_object,
                                  save_as_new="_saveasnew" in request.POST,
                                  prefix=prefix, queryset=inline.queryset(request))
                formsets.append(formset)
            # if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
            formsets_validated = all_valid(formsets)
            cross_validated = self.is_cross_valid(request, form, formsets)
            if formsets_validated and form_validated and cross_validated:
                self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)
                self.save_related(request, form, formsets, False)
                self.log_addition(request, new_object)
                return self.response_add(request, new_object)
        else:
            # Prepare the dict of initial data from the request.
            # We have to special-case M2Ms as a list of comma-separated PKs.
            initial = dict(request.GET.items())
            for k in initial:
                try:
                    f = opts.get_field(k)
                except FieldDoesNotExist:
                    continue
                if isinstance(f, ManyToManyField):
                    initial[k] = initial[k].split(",")
            if ModelForm.Meta.model._meta.module_name == 'news' and ModelForm.Meta.model._meta.object_name == 'News':
                form = ModelForm(initial=initial, user=request.user) # here I am injecting the user object into the form
                # just to be able to access the objects for this user
            else:
                form = ModelForm(initial=initial)
            prefixes = {}
            for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets(request), inline_instances):
                prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix()
                prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
                if prefixes[prefix] != 1 or not prefix:
                    prefix = "%s-%s" % (prefix, prefixes[prefix])
                formset = FormSet(instance=self.model(), prefix=prefix,
                                  queryset=inline.queryset(request))
                formsets.append(formset)

        adminForm = AdminForm(
            form, list(self.get_fieldsets(request)),
            self.get_prepopulated_fields(request),
            self.get_readonly_fields(request),
            model_admin=self)
        media = self.media + adminForm.media

        inline_admin_formsets = []
        for inline, formset in zip(inline_instances, formsets):
            fieldsets = list(inline.get_fieldsets(request))
            readonly = list(inline.get_readonly_fields(request))
            prepopulated = dict(inline.get_prepopulated_fields(request))
            inline_admin_formset = InlineAdminFormSet(
                inline, formset, fieldsets, prepopulated, readonly, model_admin=self
            )
            inline_admin_formsets.append(inline_admin_formset)
            media = media + inline_admin_formset.media

        context = {
            'title': _('Add %s') % force_text(opts.verbose_name),
            'adminform': adminForm,
            'is_popup': "_popup" in request.REQUEST,
            'media': media,
            'inline_admin_formsets': inline_admin_formsets,
            'errors': AdminErrorList(form, formsets),
            'app_label': opts.app_label,
        }
        context.update(extra_context or {})
        return self.render_change_form(request, context, form_url=form_url, add=True)
```

I really can't understand the source of my problem. Can anyone spot the issue?

Thanks!

UPDATE
As @GarryCairns suggested, I've tried to save an object from the shell. No problem with that.

```
>>> n = News.objects.create(title_en='test', slug_en='test', content_en='test')
>>> n.id
4
```

UPDATE 2:

Non translated fields are empty as well :-/ 
[image: Pre-save]
[image: Post-validation]

UPDATE 3:

```
>>> n = News()
>>> n
<News: >
>>> n.title_en = 'test'
>>> n.slug_en
>>> n.slug_en = 'test'
>>> n.content_en = 'blah blah'
>>> n.save()
>>> n.id
5
```

FIXED

It seems that both setting the ModelMultipleChoiceField queryset manually from the form **init**() and the NewsAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany() method were messing up the whole form data...

Comment: Have you tried creating and saving one of these objects in the command line? If not, try it and see if that sheds any light.

Comment: thanks @GarryCairns, there are no problems saving from the shell as you can see in the update

Comment: your update shows you creating something but not calling the save() method. Try calling that to see if some of your custom validation is being called on save() and blanking the fields. If not, then I'm stumped.

Comment: @GarryCairns I doubt if there's a difference create() and save() in terms of model validation. Anyhow, no luck :-/ (see update)