# Django InlineFormSet validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `BaseInlineFormSet`, and I'd like to validate a field in the parent form based on the values on the fields of the children. As seen in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-methods-on-an-inlineformset), the only method to make a custom validation is `clean()`, but I can't find a way to add errors to the parent form, only for the children.

In the following code I build a formula. Each variable comes from a inner form, and if the global formula don't validate, I'd like to add an error to the parent's form field `formula`

```py
class CustomInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        formula = self.instance.formula
        variables = []
        for form in self.forms:
            if 'formula_variable' in form.cleaned_data:
                variables.append(form.cleaned_data['formula_variable'])

        valid, msg = validate_formula(formula, variables)
        if not valid:
            WHAT HERE???
```

Comment: Did you try `self.add_error('formula', 'formula does not validate')`?

Comment: I get an `AttributeError`, because `self` has no attribute `add_error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Russell Keith-Magee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218383/freakboy3742), I managed to solve this. I detail the answer here for future reference.

I was doing it wrong, the InlineFormSet was not the right place to do the kind of validation I needed, it should be done in the parent ModelForm. But the parent ModelForm don't have access to the child FormSet, so I just need to pass the FormSet to the ModelForm as a parameter. So the thing looks like this now:

**The view:**

```
class FormulaCreate(CreateView):
    model = Formula
    template_name = "whatever.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ParameterRatioCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            formset = FormulaVariablesFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
            context['form'] = FormulaForm(formset=formset, data=self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
            context['formset'] = formset
        else:
            formset = FormulaVariablesFormSet(instance=self.object)
            context['form'] = FormulaForm(formset=formset, instance=self.object)
            context['formset'] = formset

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['form']
        formset = context['formset']
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            ratio = form.save()
            formset = FormulaVariablesFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=ratio)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                self.object = ratio
                return redirect(self.get_success_url())

        context['formset'] = formset
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**The Form:**

```
class FormulaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Formula

    def __init__(self, formset, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formset = formset
        super(FormulaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        variables = {}
        for form in self.formset:
            if form.is_valid() and 'formula_variable' in form.cleaned_data:
                variables[form.cleaned_data['formula_variable']] = 1

        if 'formula' in self.cleaned_data:
            formula = self.cleaned_data['formula']
            valid, msg = do_formula(formula, variables)
            if not valid:
                self._errors['formula'] = self.error_class([msg])
                del self.cleaned_data['formula']

        return self.cleaned_data
```

**The FormSet:**

```
FormulaVariablesFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Formula,
                                                FormulaVariable,
                                                extra=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at these links:

> [Validation of dependant inlines in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526792/validation-of-dependant-inlines-in-django-admin)

and

> [django - How to cross check ModelAdmin and its inlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720383/django-how-to-cross-check-modeladmin-and-its-inlines)

But it seems like the gist is that:

- the `ModelAdmin`'s `ModelForm` has a clean method that does main `Model` instance's validation
- `ModelAdmin` has access to the `InlineFormset`s (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L530)
- The `ModelForm` does not have access to the `ModelAdmin` or the `ModelAdmin`'s formsets (so it's clean method cannot cross validate the inlines)
- The `BaseModelFormSet` (`BaseInlineFormSet` extends `BaseModelFormSet`) for your inlines has a `clean` method (see https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L635) but does not have access in any way to the main `Model` instance

so what you are going to need to do is some hacking around using the top two links as a guide.