# Django form validation: get child form data in parent

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm wondering if there's a way to access Inline forms when validating the parent. For example, if my setup looks like:

**admin.py**

```
class ChildInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    form = forms.ChildInlineForm
    model = models.Child
    extra = 0


@admin.register(models.Parent)
class ParentAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    form = forms.ParentForm
    inlines = [ChildInline]
```

**models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children'
    )
```

**forms.py**

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Child
        fields = '__all__'


class ParentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Parent
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        # How would I access the ChildForm here?
```

Is there a way to access the `ChildForm` from the `ParentForm.clean()` I realize I could get parent data in the child - but my usecase involves multiple children that have data to pass to the parent - and I'd like to validate at the top level (if possible).

I've also tried doing the validation in the `model.Parent.clean()` method, but `Child` models are saved after the parent so this also seems like a non-starter.

Going off the answer below I'ev also tried using a custom formset:

```
class ParentFormSet(forms.BaseModelFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        for f in self.forms:
            print(f.cleaned_data)

class ParentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Parent
        fields = '__all__'
    formset = ParentFormSet
```

But nothing is ever printed so it doesn't seem to be accessed?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe THAT will help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893167/django-inlineformset-validation

Comment: `clean()` doesn't get called for non-inline formsets I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to override the `ModeAdmin` method `save_formset()`?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset

```
@admin.register(models.Parent)
class ParentAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    form = forms.ParentForm
    inlines = [ChildInline]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        parent_form = form
        for form_set_form in formset:
            if formset_form.is_valid():
                form_set_form_data = form_set_form.cleaned_data
                # do some validation here...
        formset.save()
```

Comment: Annoyingly if you raise a `ValidationError` here the webserver crashes.